# Convert a string which is a lists of lists to a lists of lists

Tags: python, string, list

I have seen some similar questions but it is not exactly what Im looking for. I have

```
["[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],"]
```

which is the output of a file and Im wondering how to convert it to

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

pd: it is only possible to use built-in python functions(except for eval), no external libraries allowed
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`ast.literal_eval` **safely** evaluates the argument

```
import ast
l= ['[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],']
l[0]=list(ast.literal_eval(l[0]))
```

Comment: It is not possible to use external libraries

Comment: @franco can you use ```eval``` then?

Comment: no, not possible